# Problem with understanding reference types

Tags: .net, silverlight, telerik, reference-type

I get from WCF service ObservableCoolection

```
MyTypes = e.Result;

ObservableCollection<MyType> MyTypes // it's a property of _myTypes

<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdSrL" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypes}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyType, Mode=TwoWay}"

public ShowroomLog SelectedMyType
{
    get { return _selectedMyType; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedSMyType != value)
        {
            _selectedMyType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedMyTypePropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

after I get those collection from web service, selected item is set by grid, and after that I do:

```
SelectedMyType = null;
```

Why after that none of item from collection isn't null?

if I do:

```
var x = new Car();
var y = x;
```

and

```
y = null;
```

then x would be also null;

Why there is different?

Comment: "then x would be also null" - are you sure? Maybe a quick console app to test this hypothesis...

Comment: I am assuming `_selectedSMyType` is a typo and should be `_selectedMyType`

Comment: Have you tried your own example with `x`, `y`, and `Car`?  So long as `Car` is declared as a class, x is not null like you you've commented, x is still the new Car. If you want to understand reference types better, I always found it useful to consider the objects your variables contain to be detached.  That's because, they are.  Your variables `x` and `y` are just a reference to the Car object you created.  When you say `var y = x;` you're actually creating a NEW reference to the same object.  When you say `y = null;` you're saying delete this reference to the object. Hope that helps?

Comment: so many years in a lie...thanks a lot. So how can I destroy car? by dispose or waiting for GC, yes?

Comment: @user278618 `Dispose` is only appropriate for an object that itself is responsible for non-managed (read: non-.NET) things. For a stand-alone pure managed object, yes, just stop 'looking at it' (ie make sure there are no references to it) and GC will take care of it.

Comment: In your case @user278618, it would depend on the _scope_ of the variables.  If they were local variables within a method for example, the variables would move out of scope when the method exited, and the references to the car would therefore be destroyed.  At a later stage, the GC will look at all the objects you created, will find the car object, and notice that there are no longer any references pointing at the car, so it destroys the car.

Comment: @user278618 - I don't know if this will help, certainly the formatting google docs has assigned isn't helpful, but I stuck a quick example of the difference between reference and value types [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FZ0Kmh0hLamh_bvyUUl2Ma7jCEQHzKBbRG34qKgwfBU/edit?hl=en_US) <- a word document containing a console app you can copy/paste into VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types in C# are effectively object pointers. In your example `x` and `y` are object pointers, not the objects themselves. If you change a pointer you do not change the object. x **would not** *also become null* as you state. That assumption/example is incorrect.

If you called `.Clear()` on the collection via either variable, then both pointers to that collection will show 0 entries, **but you need to explain what it is you are trying to do so I can explain with a specific example.**

`.Clear()` would not however destroy any children in the list if there are referenced elsewhere (e.g. by another list).

Comment: I know that there are pointers, like _selectedMyType . So if I have good understanding that ObservableCollection is not collection of pointers?

Comment: ObservableCollection *is* a collection of pointers. *(If the children are value types I think they get boxed automatically, but I am not 100% sure)*. The point is (no pun intended) that if you change a pointer/variable you do not change all other pointers/variables referring to the same object.